# Uniform convergence of $g_n(t)=e^{-nt}h(t)$ where $h(t)\to0$ as $t\to0$ and $h$ is bounded on $(0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

> Let $h:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ be bounded, and suppose that $\lim\limits_{t\searrow0}\,h(t)=0$. Define $g_n(t)=e^{-nt}h(t)$ for $t>0$. Show that $g_n\overset{u}{\longrightarrow}0$ on $(0,\infty).$

$\textbf{Proof Attempt:}$ Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given, and let $M>0$ be an upper bound for $\vert h\vert$. Since $\lim\limits_{t\searrow0}\,h(t)=0$, we can choose $0<\delta<1$ small enough such that $\vert h(t)\vert<\varepsilon$ for all $0<t\leq\delta$. Then for all $t\in(0,\delta]$ and all $n\in\mathbb N$ we have
$$\vert g_n(t)\vert=\left\vert\frac{h(t)}{e^{nt}}\right\vert\leq\varepsilon.$$
Therefore, $g_n(t)\overset{u}{\longrightarrow}0$ on $(0,\delta].$

On the other hand, since $h$ is bounded on $[\delta,\infty)$, we have for all $t\in[\delta,\infty)$ that
$$\vert g_n(t)\vert=\left\vert\frac{h(t)}{e^{nt}}\right\vert\leq\frac{M}{e^{n\delta}}\overset{u}{\longrightarrow}0.$$
Altogether we have that $g_n(t)\overset{u}{\longrightarrow}0$ on $(0,\infty)$.

---

Can anyone please proofread my proof above?

Thank you for your time and appreciate any help.

Comment: Your proof is fine.

Comment: Very good...................